# Build failed with an exception: ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'destinationDir'

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build

I'm trying to build my project it is returning following error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>   Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'destinationDir' during up-to-date check.
>   Could not read path 'D:\Android\Projects\appName\app\build\intermediates\javac\debug\compileDebugJavaWithJavac\classes\android\support\v7\appcompat'.

this was working fine upto sometime back, no changes in code were made, nor any update on Android studio or SDK

I have tried following things

- Clean Porject
- Rebuild Project
- Invalidate caches and restart
- Manually deleting the build folder.
- Disabled "Instant Run"

Problem seems to be with 
`D:\Android\Projects\ProjectName\app\build\intermediates\javac\debug\compileDebugJavaWithJavac\classes\android\support\v7\appcompat` folder.

When I'm trying to manually delete the folder it is showing `Access denied` although I have Administrative rights to my account. Tried deleting same folder using `cmd (Run as Administrator)` also, still it is showing `Access Denied`.